# Bind event to dynamically created div

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a div with a span on the spot using jquery, like so

```
$("[data-modal]").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var container = $("<div></div>").addClass("modal m-form").appendTo(document.body);
    var close = $("<span></span>").addClass("modal-close").appendTo(container);
}
```

so far so good...

Then, i'm binding an event to the selector **modal-close**, like so

```
$(".modal-close").click(function(event) {
    alert("close the dialog");
});
```

That one doesn't work, so i've tried this one, with no success:

```
$(".modal-close").on("click", function(event) {         
    alert('close the dialog');
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind it to the next static parent.
Means if you have a parent element that never gets changed, bind it to this (in your case maybe a wrapper for the whole modal). 
If you haven't a static wrapper around, you can also bind it to the document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal-close', function(event) {
    alert("close the dialog");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind event to dynamically created element you can use `.on()`. You have used `.on()` incorrectly, please check below code -

```
$(document).on("click",".modal-close", function(event) {
    alert("close the dialog");
});
```

**[More Information for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**